# How do you call this kind of graph?

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

I'm trying to find out what's the name of a kind of graph with the following properties:

1. Every vertex is connected by at most D edges to any other vertex
2. Every vertex has exactly W edges

Here are two examples:

[image]

It's possible to reach any vertex with two "transitions" or less, and each vertex has exactly three edges.

I came across this while studying network topologies. Coming from a software engineering background it reminds me of balanced trees. I tried searching for "balanced graphs" but it seems to apply to other situations.

Do you know how it's called?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The singular form of *vertices* is *vertex*.

Comment: @RobPratt Fixed. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every vertex having exactly $W$ edges means each vertex has degree $W$, and the graph would be called $W$-regular. Every vertex being connected by at most $D$ edges to every other vertex means that the diameter of the graph is at most $D$ (exactly $D$ if there is some pair of vertices where the shortest path connecting them contains exactly $D$ edges).

Therefore, a graph having both properties you list would be called a $W$-regular graph with diameter $D$.